# NameError: name 'dishID' is not defined. Did you mean: 'dishid'?

Tags: python, mysql, function, mysql-connector

this is the code of the following function

Function:

```py
def dishID():
    query = 'select count(*), max(DishID) from Dish'
    cur.execute(query)
    fetch = cur.fetchall()
    for i in fetch:
        if i[0] == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return (int(i[1]) + 1)
```

Error code

```py
dishname = input('Enter Dish Name: ')
        dishprice = input('Enter Dish Price: ')
        dishid = str(dishID())
        query = 'insert into Dish values({}, {}, {})'.format(
            dishname, dishprice, dishid)
        cur.execute(query)
        con.commit()
        print("Dish has added successfully")
```

Full code: https://srcb.in/l1RdtphmhF

This is code is restaurant Database management system. I am taking the help of mysql and making this system. all the functions work fine but when i call the dishID function it produces an error where it cant read the function. To be precise i want the code to work so it can insert some values

Comment: We need to see your full code to understand why `dishID` is not in scope. We just don't have enough info to help you at all even if we wanted to. Please post a [mre]. You mention "**attached img**" but there's no image attached. It sounds though that that info wouldn't be relevant. Plus, it should likely be posted as text, rather than an image, even if it was relevant.

Comment: i added the whole code. Tho i attached the img idk y it didnt attach itself. I think you can get the structure of the table from line 22

Comment: You must put the full [mre] into your post, not in an external link - see [ask]: "**also copy the code into the question itself**. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time." I will say though that that code is **NOT** a minimal example. It's just your full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I looked at your link and the issue is extremely simple; you defined the function `dishID` only after you actually call it. Here's a simple example of this issue - here's some code that works fine:

```py
def test_function():
    print('hi')

test_function()
```

```
Output: hi
```

Versus this code, which references `test_function` before its definition:

```py
test_function()

def test_function():
    print('hi')
```

```
Output: NameError: name 'test_function' is not defined
```

Comment: was that it all? but i have defined so many functions after calling it. y does this work this way

Comment: well.. that did work to some extent but gave an `Unknown column 'pizza' in 'field list'` at line 99

Comment: @oreoooohh that's a totally separate issue. It's absolutely fine to make another post about it, but on this site, it's one issue per post.

Comment: Also, the reason why all the other functions worked is just because Python reads everything in top-down order. You have `signin()` right before the definition of `dishID`, but it's after all the other definitions. Meaning, all the other definitions, except `def dishID`, would've already run before `signin()`. Makes sense?